# How do we find the minium of $f(z)=-|z|^2+|z|^4$?

Tags: complex-analysis, maxima-minima

Consider a function $f(z)$ of a complex variable $z=re^{i\theta}$ given by $f(z)=-|z|^2+|z|^4$. This function, when plotted gives the famous mexican hat potential with the minima lying on a circle $r=1/\sqrt{2}$.

But the minimisation condition requires $f_{rr}>0$ and $D\equiv f_{rr}f_{\theta\theta}-f^2_{r\theta}>0$. But in this case, it turns out that $D=0$ for all values of $z$ since $f(z)=f(|z|)=f(r)$.

How does this clash with the minimization requirement?

Comment: The minimization condition is a sufficient condition. It is not necessary.

Comment: That condition is for isolated extrema, i.e. extrema with the property that there is some neighborhood around them where there are no other extrema. This function lacks that property. It is also a sufficient condition, as you know from the 1D case with $f(x)=x^4$.

Comment: Couldn't you just minimize $r \mapsto r^4 - r^2$? The extrema are attained for $r \in \left\{0, \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$.

Comment: Yes, but it just depends on $r = |z|$. You then know that the extrema are $0$ and the circle $|z| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Agree. But doesn't $D=0$ clash with the minimization requirement?

Comment: @SRS I believe the test with the Hessian works only for isolated extrema, so the explanation by lisyarus is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to incorporate both @lisyarus and @gimusi answers. Lets calculate the gradient and Hessian explicitly

$$f\left(z=re^{i\theta}\right)=-r^{2}+r^{4}$$

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}f=\begin{pmatrix}-2r+4r^{3}\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$H\left(f\right)=\begin{pmatrix}-2+12r^{2}&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

As you can see, the gradient vanishes at $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for every value of $\theta$ - this means, as @lisyarus said, that this extermum is not isolated.  The Hessian is

$$H\left(f\right)_{r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\begin{pmatrix}4&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The structure of this matrix tells you more than its determinant. The requirements that

$$\begin{cases}f_{rr}>0\\D\equiv f_{rr}f_{\theta\theta}-f^2_{r\theta}>0\end{cases}$$

are necessary and sufficient condition for $H\left(f\right)$ to be **positive definite** (which is only a **sufficient** for a point to be a minimum). This is equivalent to say that both eigenvalues of $H\left(f\right)$ are positive. But you can clearly see that this is not the case, since our eigenvalues are

$$\begin{cases}\lambda_{r}=4\\\lambda_{\theta}=0\end{cases}$$

The eigenvalue in the $r$ direction is $\lambda_{r}=4$, which tells you that as you walk on lines of $\theta=\rm const.$ you get a minimum at $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. That's what @gimusi showed in his\her answer. On the other hand, the zero eigenvalue in the $\theta$ direction, $\lambda_{\theta}=0$, tells you that the function is flat as you walk on the circle $r=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is the determinant of the Hessian matrix. For the mexican hat, you don't have a point minimum, but a whole 1-dimensional subspace of minima. In this case, the Hessian will be zero along the tangent of this subspace. Thus, the whole 2x2 Hessian will be degenerate, having 0 among its eigenvalues, and its determinant is surely 0.

Comment: That's true. But what is the correct minimization condition in this case?
 @lisyarus

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;f(z)=\big(|z|^2\big)^2-|z|^2=\left(|z|^2-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{4} \ge -\frac{1}{4}\,$ with equality iff $\,|z|^2=\frac{1}{2}\,$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.